# Patching IsDebuggerPresent stops breakpoints in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I am using [MinHook.NET](https://github.com/CCob/MinHook.NET) to patch some API calls. The purpose for this is some Anti Anti-Debug functions.

However, it seems that when I patch `IsDebuggerPresent`, it stops breakpoints being hit in Visual Studio. If i set a breakpoint in Visual Studio and debug, the breakpoint never gets hit and the code doesn't stop.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET Framework 4.8

`External.Auth` uses P/Invoke to call a shared C library. I do not have control over this library and it was built by a 3rd party. This library unfortunately has anti-debug code built in which stops me from debugging my application in Visual Studio. I cannot ask for the anti-debug code to be removed from the library.

Full code is below:

```
    internal class Program
    {

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int NtSetInformationThread(IntPtr handle, uint threadInfoClass, IntPtr threadInfo, uint threadInfoLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool IsDebuggerPresent();

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        delegate bool IsDebuggerPresentDelegate();

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        delegate int NtSetInformationThreadDelegate(IntPtr handle, uint threadInfoClass, IntPtr threadInfo, uint threadInfoLength);

        static NtSetInformationThreadDelegate NtSetInformationThread_orig;
        static IsDebuggerPresentDelegate IsDebuggerPresent_orig;


        static int NtSetInformationThread_detour(IntPtr handle, uint threadInfoClass, IntPtr threadInfo, uint threadInfoLength)
        {
            if (threadInfoClass == 0x11)
            {
                return 0x0;
            }
            return NtSetInformationThread_orig(handle, threadInfoClass, threadInfo, threadInfoLength);
        }

        static bool IsDebuggerPresent_detour()
        {
            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            using (HookEngine engine = new HookEngine())
            {
                IsDebuggerPresent_orig =
                    engine.CreateHook("kernel32.dll", "IsDebuggerPresent", new IsDebuggerPresentDelegate(IsDebuggerPresent_detour));

                NtSetInformationThread_orig =
                    engine.CreateHook("ntdll.dll", "NtSetInformationThread", new NtSetInformationThreadDelegate(NtSetInformationThread_detour));

                engine.EnableHooks();
                MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            await External.Auth("xxx", false);
            Console.WriteLine("got past auth");
        }
    }
```

How can I continue to use MinHook to patch these API calls, but still have debug functionality in Visual Studio?

Thanks

Comment: Only patch in Release builds you'll ship?

Comment: That doesn't help. I want to patch so I can debug during development of the project.